# $\pi(z)\otimes\delta(r-r_0) = \sqrt{r_0^2 - z^2}\,\delta\left(r-\sqrt{r_0^2 - z^2}\right)$?

Tags: geometry, convolution

I'm trying to solve for $\boldsymbol{\pi}(z)$ in a purported equivalence relation:

$\boldsymbol{\pi}(z)\otimes\delta(r-r_0) = \sqrt{r_0^2 - z^2}\,\delta\left(r-\sqrt{r_0^2 - z^2}\right)$

where $\boldsymbol{\pi}(z)$ is an "xy-plane" (in some sense) convolved with a sphere $\delta(r-r_0)$ of radius $r_0$.

Is there *any* solution for $\boldsymbol{\pi}(z)$ that would make this identity hold? If so, what exactly is that interpretation?

Comment: Cross-breeding may give strange results... Where have you seen this very strange result ? You are right to ask what the plane really is here as a function or distribution ?

Comment: What if it's a 2D radial DiracDelta distribution (ie: a circle) that starts at a point intersection and, as it travels along the z-axis for the covolution, expands to a circle the same diameter as the 3D radial DiracDelta distribution (ie: a sphere) and then ends up at the other end as a point tangent again?